# How to solve the error that comes out when installing opencv 3.1 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have tried to install opencv 3.1 in ubuntu 16.04, because I need to do an algorithm in c ++ with opencv, I have followed the steps of different tutorials but none has worked for me, the only one with which I have advanced more is this:

https://github.com/cesco345/StemApks/blob/master/TutorialsNotebook%20(1).ipynb

But when I get to the cmake step, I get these errors,

```
 -- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:18 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
 CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
 of the following names:

 Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
 qt5core-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
 been installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:19 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
 CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
 of the following names:

 Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
 qt5gui-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
 provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
 installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:20 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
 has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
 "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
 any of the following names:

 Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
 qt5widgets-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
 been installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:21 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5Test.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
 asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test", but
 CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Test" with any
 of the following names:

 Qt5TestConfig.cmake
 qt5test-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Test" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Qt5Test_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "Qt5Test" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
 been installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:22 (find_package):
 By not providing "FindQt5Concurrent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
 project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
 "Qt5Concurrent", but CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Concurrent"
 with any of the following names:

 Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
 qt5concurrent-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Concurrent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
 "Qt5Concurrent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "Qt5Concurrent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
 has been installed.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such 
 file or directory
 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1326 (message):
 Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake:34 (find_package)
 CMakeLists.txt:535 (include)


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
 See also "/home/jenny/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
 See also "/home/jenny/opencv-3.1.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

which I do not solve, someone who has some idea how to solve it to install it or someone who has a good tutorial that I can follow so I can install opencv in ubuntu please.

Comment: I suggest you to remove qt5 support... a simple solution is to use `ccmake` or the gui interface of `cmake`. So check the components you need. Let me know. I build `OpenCV 3.1` for a lot of kind of CPU using Ubuntu 16.04 without any problem.

Comment: You know you can use `OpenCV` and `C++` in Windows, Mac and in almost any other popular S.O., right?

Comment: Yes, I already know that exists for windows, but when compiling and running the code is faster in ubuntu, that's why I'm installing it, I just had some errors

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal `cd` to your build folder. Run `ccmake ..`, use arrow keys to navigate between the pages, on the last page, arrow down to `WITH_QT`, enter to turn it off. Press `c` to configure and `g` to generate.

In future use [this link](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) for best result.

Comment: says "command not found"

Comment: Finish the install but when i try to run a sample show this error "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

Comment: @Colours123 CMake should have downloaded IPP when building OpenCV. Try running `sudo ldconfig`. If you want to disable IPP, from build directory run `ccmake ..`, arrow down to `WITH_IPP`, enter to disable, press `c` then `g`. Run `make` again.